# Paste an HTTP request directly into postman to send

Tags: http, postman

By an http request, I mean something like:

```
POST /service/controller.asmx/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: ...

xmlFile=string&xmlFile=string
```

Is there a way to paste a request in this format into postman to send, like I can paste into the Body tab?

I can go the other way around and get a string like this by going to the Code button and selecting HTTP from the dropdown, but pasting into that box seems not to take.

I want to do this to avoid going to each tab seperately and configuring each thing individually, including the URL and request type.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot paste that string into Postman.

You should consider pasting the cURL version of the code into your terminal (if you use Linux).

It's enough for quick one-offs.